# Spark on YARN : Job Submitted v/s Accepted?

Tags: apache-spark

I am running spark job on YARN-cluster mode . What is the difference between YARN Accepted and YARN Submitted status ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We submit the spark job using spark-submit (cluster mode YARN).

**YARN submitted:** Job has submitted to the YARN scheduler queue (FIFO/Fair scheduler) and waiting for its turn.

**YARN accepted:** YARN has started execution of the job but only application master is running, Application master has not got resources from the resource manager to run the job.